# Parsing XML in a method returns nothing

Tags: java, xml, parsing, nodes, nodelist

```
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse("15122021.xml");
            NodeList currencyList= doc.getElementsByTagName("Currency");
            for(int i=0;i<currencyList.getLength();i++){
                Node p = currencyList.item(i);
                if(p.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element mainTag = (Element) p;
                    NodeList currencySellPriceList= mainTag.getElementsByTagName("ForexSelling");
                    NodeList currencyBuyPriceList = mainTag.getElementsByTagName("ForexBuying");
                    NodeList currencyNameList2= mainTag.getElementsByTagName("CurrencyName");
                    for(int j=0;j<currencyNameList2.getLength();j++){
                        Node c=currencyNameList2.item(j);
                        Node cbp=currencyBuyPriceList.item(j);
                        Node csp=currencySellPriceList.item(j);
                        if(c.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE && cbp.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE && csp.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                            System.out.println("Currency name: "+c.getTextContent());
                            System.out.println("Buy price: "+cbp.getTextContent());
                            System.out.println("Sell price: "+csp.getTextContent());

                        }
                    }
                }


            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

I am trying to parse XML file like this in main method and it works.But when i try to take this code block to another method like this

```
public class XMLScraperBuilder {

    public NodeList getBuyPrices() throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        NodeList currencySellPriceList=null;

            DocumentBuilder builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse("15122021.xml");
            NodeList currencyList= doc.getElementsByTagName("Currency");
            for(int i=0;i<currencyList.getLength();i++){
                Node currency = currencyList.item(i);
                if(currency.getNodeType()==Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                    Element mainTag = (Element) currency;
                     currencySellPriceList= mainTag.getElementsByTagName("ForexSelling");
                     for(int j=0;j<currencySellPriceList.getLength();j++){
                          Node c = currencySellPriceList.item(j);

                     }


    }}
        return currencySellPriceList;
    }}
```

It returns nothing when i try to print the NodeList with a for loop in my main method(after creating an object from XMLScraperBuilder).Any ideas?

Comment: Just as a recomendation, with `e.getMessage()` you lose track of everything, no stacktrace to check. If printing in console use directly `e.printStacktrace()`

Comment: Thanks for recomendation.Couldn't figure it out if i was getting error it is just for checking the error message.

Comment: You are setting currencySellPriceList repeatedly, once for every Currency element encountered.  If the last Currency element in the document has no ForexSelling descendants, that is what will be returned, regardless of whether other Currency elements have such descendants.

Comment: Actually i figured it out (finally :)).I can directly reach to ForexSelling NodeList without going through Currency's child nodes.